# Datatable not being filled?

Tags: c#, asp.net

After creating a new datatable, the dataset does not fill the datatable with the 50 columns it should, I get an empty datatable.

```
List<DataTable> test = new List<DataTable>();                
foreach (string currentconstring in constrings)
{
    started = false;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
    test.Add(dt);
    Thread connectthread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        started = true;
        DataTable localdt = dt;
        try
        {
             // access the database
            MySqlConnection mySqlconnection = new MySqlConnection(currentconstring); //Connects to the MySQL database with the current connection string
            mySqlconnection.Open();
            MySqlCommand SqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(_sqlQuery, mySqlconnection); //Sends the specified query to the server
            MySqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand);

            SqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);  //Fill Dataset
            localdt = _dataSet.Tables[0];

            mySqlconnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Most likely you are entering the catch but not noticing it.

Comment: That is not the case

Comment: Looking at the code, you're using a few class names as variable names (`SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`).

Comment: Are you checking `localdt` DataTable or `dt` while checking if you have got data or not.?? If you are expecting to have data in `List<DataTable> test` list, it would not be present there.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a thread and passed it a delegate (function), but you have not started the thread.

Try to put `connectthread.Start();` after declaring the thread.

You might need to wait for the thread to finish so might have to use `Thread.Join()`.

You might want to use `async/await` as that would be better than creating threads on your own, also you are sharing a data structure which is being written to without using `locks`. Please do check the regular problems when using multi threading.